# GitHub Pages images not loading (do load if paste the img url in browser)

Tags: github, github-pages, docusaurus

I take a screenshot and press paste on the edit page of a markdown file and GitHub until a couple of months ago used to insert:

```
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1001172/230591231-3846ae09-107c-48e3-8840-52ba965f6a31.png)
```

I've not edited a page in a couple of months but the code inserted is now:

```
![image](https://github.com/KevinUK/OKZestDocs/assets/1001172/e984549c-b92c-4ef4-824f-25901486852f)
```

When I load my website, I see this in the console log for this newly inserted image:

```
responded with a status of 404 ()
```

However, if you go to **https://github.com/KevinUK/OKZestDocs/assets/1001172/e984549c-b92c-4ef4-824f-25901486852f** directly in the browser then the image loads!

I am using Docusaurus.

How do I get my newly inserted images to load?

Thanks!